# Shared memory in mpi4py

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, shared-memory, mpi4py, memoryview

I use a `MPI` (`mpi4py`) script (on a single node), which works with a very large object. In order to let all processes have access to the object, I distribute it through `comm.bcast()`. This copies the object to all processes and consumes a lot of memory, especially during the copying process. Therefore, I would like to share something like a pointer instead of the object itself. I found some features in `memoryview` useful to boost work with the object inside a process. Also the object's real memory address is accessible through the `memoryview` object string representation and can be distributed like this:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank:
    content_pointer = comm.bcast(root = 0)
    print(rank, content_pointer)
else:
    content = ''.join(['a' for i in range(100000000)]).encode()
    mv = memoryview(content)
    print(mv)
    comm.bcast(str(mv).split()[-1][: -1], root = 0)
```

This prints:

```
<memory at 0x7f362a405048>
1 0x7f362a405048
2 0x7f362a405048
...
```

That's why I believe that there must be a way to reconstitute the object in another process. However, I cannot find a clue in the documentation about how to do it.

In short, my question is: **Is it possible to share an object between processes on the same node in `mpi4py`?**

Comment: could you accept the new MPI 3.0 answer of JobJob as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know much about mpi4py, but this should not be possible from the MPI point of view. MPI stands for Message Passing Interface, which means exactly that: pass messages around between processes. You could try and use [MPI One-sided communication](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/mpi4py.html#one-sided-communications) to resemble something like a globally accessible memory, but otherwise process memory is unavailable to other processes.

If you need to rely on a large block of shared Memory, you need to utilize something like OpenMP or threads, which you absolutely could use on a single node. A hybrid parallelization with MPI and some shared memory parallelization would allow you to have one shared memory block per node, but still the option to utilize many nodes.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in light of MPI 3.0 shared memory (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-mpi-3-shared-memory-in-xeon-phi-processors)

Comment: @BenThompson OK, you want me to delete it or change the answer? I have 0 experience with this new feature...

Answer (score 18):

Here's a simple example of shared memory using MPI, very slightly modified from https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mpi4py/Fme1n9niNwQ/lk3VJ54WAQAJ

You can run it with: `mpirun -n 2 python3 shared_memory_test.py` (assuming you saved it as shared_memory_test.py)

```
from mpi4py import MPI 
import numpy as np 

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 

# create a shared array of size 1000 elements of type double
size = 1000 
itemsize = MPI.DOUBLE.Get_size() 
if comm.Get_rank() == 0: 
    nbytes = size * itemsize 
else: 
    nbytes = 0

# on rank 0, create the shared block
# on rank 1 get a handle to it (known as a window in MPI speak)
win = MPI.Win.Allocate_shared(nbytes, itemsize, comm=comm) 

# create a numpy array whose data points to the shared mem
buf, itemsize = win.Shared_query(0) 
assert itemsize == MPI.DOUBLE.Get_size() 
ary = np.ndarray(buffer=buf, dtype='d', shape=(size,)) 

# in process rank 1:
# write the numbers 0.0,1.0,..,4.0 to the first 5 elements of the array
if comm.rank == 1: 
    ary[:5] = np.arange(5)

# wait in process rank 0 until process 1 has written to the array
comm.Barrier() 

# check that the array is actually shared and process 0 can see
# the changes made in the array by process 1
if comm.rank == 0: 
    print(ary[:10])
```

Should output this (printed from process rank 0):

```
[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: What about a multi-dimensional array, let's say np.zeros((50, 50, 50))?

Comment: @Zézouille for a multi-dim array it's similar, you'd just make (approximately) the following changes:
`size = 1000` to `shape = (50,50,50)`, `size = np.prod(shape)` and this line becomes `ary = np.ndarray(buffer=buf, dtype='d', shape=shape) # instead of shape=(size,)`

and to get this particular example to run you'd also want to change
`ary[:5] = np.arange(5)` to `ary[:5, 1, 1] = np.arange(5)` and
`print(ary[:10])` to `print(ary[:10, 1, 1])`

Comment: @JobJob Do you have any idea if that would be possible with a dictionary?